# How to include CLR in build? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, build, clr

I want to distribute standalone software, but the "Build" option in VB.NET doesn't include the CLR. I don't want to hassle users with downloading the CLR, is there some way I can include it in the build?

Answer (score 1):

No, it needs to be installed as a standalone component. You can get reduced size redistributables, but something has to be installed.

Comment: Also this isn't really a problem as Windows Vista comes with .NET 3.0 anyway, but you can include the .NET 3.5 and 4.0 "Client profile" redistributables with your application, if not links to them.

Comment: Additionally, Visual Studio "Setup" projects will automatically include the .NET Fx.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an Installer with Net included, use WiX. It is a full blown installer + bootstrapper for free. But expect a day or two while you figure thinks out - it is a complex topic and WiX is like every other OSS product: The documentation is as usefull as hard rock at cleaning your posterior....